# Ставится ли запятая перед союзом как в предложении

Tags: запятая

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая перед союзом как в предложении "Площадь круга растёт как квадрат радиуса" и почему. Смысл предложения такой: площадь круга растет пропорционально квадрату радиуса круга, например, если радиус круга вырос в 3 раза, то площадь круга выросла в 3*3=9 раз.

Большое спасибо.

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос из Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН:
"Мы думаем, что в данном случае запятая не нужна, т. к. содержание оборота тесно связано по смыслу со сказуемым. Но, если мы все правильно поняли, формулировка предложения неудачна и лучше было бы выразиться иначе."
Я не привел оригинальное предложение, поскольку оно изобилует специальными терминами.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сравнительный оборот с союзом "как" в значении "подобно" выделяется запятыми

Comment: Это не сравнительный оборот.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна. Можно заменить на "пропорционально квадрату радиуса", но и так хорошо. Нормальная формулировка.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, запятая не нужна.

Почему? -- нет причин её ставить :)

Это не сравнительный оборот и не придаточное предложение.

(моё кредо: сложные правила вредны, их всё равно не удаётся использовать)

Comment: Большинство простых и сложных правил можно заменить грамматическим анализом (очень рекомендую). "Как квадрат радиуса" - изначально это сравнительный оборот, но в предложении такая конструкция может являться не только сравнительным оборотом, но и необособленным обстоятельством образа действия. Сравните: (1)"Площадь круга растёт как квадрат радиуса (пропорционально квадрату радиуса)". (2) "Площадь круга, как и квадрат радиуса, растёт". Но мы же не то сказать хотели.

Comment: рекомендация хорошая, но мне приходит в голову другое. Мы видим случай перевода на русский с языка математики. 
На языке математики это равенство. При переводе подбирается ближайшее языковое средство - будем называть его сравнительным оборотом ("как"). Т.е. это НЕ сравнение изначально. 
Далее см. мой ответ выше.

Comment: Площадь круга растёт так, как  квадрат радиуса".  Перед нами тот же оборот с союзом КАК и уже с обязательным обособлением. Обороты с союзом КАК (со значением сравнения, соответствия, тождества, уподобления) чаще обособляются, чем не обособляются. Соответственно, для решения задачи нельзя обойтись одним отрицанием "это не сравнительный оборот и не придаточное предложение", но надо обозначить структуру простого предложения и назвать синтаксическую роль необособленного оборота.